# Low performance for nested DataGrid while have a lot of columns

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF application that contains a datagrid and nested datagrid (RowDetailsTemplate).
For each row have a datagrid that have 1000 rows inside.
I see that nested datagrid have a low performance while i open that.

I also try to set grid height and VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True", VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling".
but without successes..

The xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="TestMasterDetails.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <DataGrid 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                        VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Content="+" Click="HandleExpandCollapseForRow"></Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"  Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"  Width="100"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="LastName" Binding="{Binding LastName}"  Width="100"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="400">
                    <DataGrid 
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Addresses}"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                        VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" >
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}" Width="100"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The MainWindow code behind:

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    VM.VM _vm = new VM.VM();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = _vm;
    }

    private void HandleExpandCollapseForRow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button expandCollapseButton = (Button)sender;
        DataGridRow selectedRow = DataGridRow.GetRowContainingElement(expandCollapseButton);

        if (null != expandCollapseButton && "+" == expandCollapseButton.Content.ToString())
        {
            selectedRow.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            expandCollapseButton.Content = "-";
        }
        else
        {
            selectedRow.DetailsVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            expandCollapseButton.Content = "+";
        }
    }
}
```

The ViewModel:

```
  public class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    List<PersonModel> _persons = new List<PersonModel>();

    public List<PersonModel> Persons
    {
        get { return _persons; }
        set
        {
            if (_persons != value)
            {
                _persons = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Persons");
            }
        }
    }
    const int ZERO = 0;
    const int LENGTH = 1000;
    public VM()
    {
        for (int i = ZERO; i < LENGTH; i++)
        {
            var person = new PersonModel() { FirstName = "FirstName" + i.ToString(), Id = i, LastName = "LastName" + i.ToString() };
            for (int j = ZERO; j < LENGTH; j++)
            {
                person.Addresses.Add(new AddressModel() { Id = j, Address = "Address" + j.ToString() });
            }
            _persons.Add(person);
        }
    }
}
```